# Error in Bash script arithmetic syntax

Tags: bash

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
vpct=5.3 
echo $((vpct*15))
```

Error:

```
./abc.sh: line 5: 5.3: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".3")
```

I know I don't need a script to multiply `5.3 * 15`, but this small script to single out the error. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides `bc`, there are other tools you can tools you can try

```
awk -v vpct="$VPCT" 'BEGIN{print vpct * 15}'

echo $vpct | ruby -e 'print gets.to_f * 15 '

echo  "$vpct 15 * p" | dc
```

Comment: Since you are listing alternatives, if you use zsh instead of bash the script will simply work.

Answer (score 8):

According to http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml:

> Bash does not understand floating point arithmetic. It treats numbers containing a decimal point as strings.

You should use bc to perform such calculations, just as in dogbane's solution, except that you should escape the expression using quotes so the `*` character doesn't cause unwanted shell expansion.

```
echo "$vpct*15" | bc
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use bc for floating point arithmetic:

```
echo "$vpct*15" | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

$(( $vpct * 15 )) // (add a $ sign should do it)

Comment: --sorry I cannot try these solution, but will be happy if one of these works out for you :)

Comment: ./abc.sh: line 5: 5.3*15 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".3*15 ")
Neither work

Comment: sorry Humble and dogbane - at least above is a link to the same problem

Comment: Dollar signs aren't necessary in an arithmetic context in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Shebang should be written like `#!`
And anyway `$(())` is only for integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ksh available, it will do float arithmetic.