# Arithmetic syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I have array with float values in it:

```
declare -x args=(20.5 60 14)
total=10000

for i in ${args[@]}; do
    max=$((total/${#args[@]}*i/100)) | bc
done
```

> syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")

So much for using `bc`, since it fails even when trying to apply the suggestions here:

- [Error in bash script arithmetic syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040784/error-in-bash-script-arithmetic-syntax)
- [Arithmetic syntax error with shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211368/arithmetic-syntax-error-with-shell-script)

Maybe I just don't know what the hell I'm doing...

Comment: What is the match you are trying out here? is it `1000/3*20.5/100`? It does not make sense to me

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Shell arithmetic in Bash only supports integer calculations.

Comment: Change the args values to whole numbers and it works, that's the functionality I need with float values.

Comment: @JackO'Leary: For example is it `1000/(3*20.5/100)` ?

Comment: @JackO'Leary Are you sure that's the right precedence? It's not the same as in your code.

Comment: @JackO'Leary: when you claim math isn't right on a answer, take an effort to explain how the math works out. Your input is no way readable to understand the precedence

Comment: There shouldn't be parentheses around the numbers, it changes the result.

Comment: Division and multiplication have the same precedence, so if there are no parentheses, it's simply left-to-right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$(( ...))` is telling bash to do the math which it shouldn't be doing. Instead put the whole line to the right of  the `=` in `$(.)` and make the inside look like `echo "..." | bc`

```
   max=$( echo "$total/${#args[@]}*$i/100" | bc)
```

Comment: I need it to do math though.

Comment: bc should do the math. Bash only does basic integer math.  Feed bc the math to do and capture the bc output.

Comment: On each iteration of the loop I get `(standard_in) 1: parse error`.

Comment: This means that bc doesn't like the input it is getting. I would send the echo part to the screen to see what it looks like. If it looks ok, pass it into bc on the command line and adjust it until bc likes it, then put those adjustments into the script.

Comment: For bc, you may need to tell it to use decimal places. Put the string.  scale=6;  in front of the math in the echo statement

Comment: Okay the mistake was the two `))` in your example. Take those out and it works.

Comment: You re right the )) should have been a ). If you look at the echo output and send it to bc on a command line, does bc give errors?

Comment: Take out the other `)` also after 100 otherwise the statement is unbalanced. I can accept the answer then...

Comment: @jack O'Leary: I made the change. Thanks!